# How to download xcode4 from windows pc (with IDP acc)

Tags: windows, macos, download, xcode4

I was not able to download xcode4 from windows pc, even with valid iphone developer program account.

No success even after spoofing the useragent string as mac safari with firefox.

IMG 1: No download link by default

http://qcfailed.tumblr.com/photo/1280/3780861509/1/tumblr_lhvuwqehHA1qem6ty

IMG 2: Download link after spoofing useragent

http://qcfailed.tumblr.com/photo/1280/3780861509/2/tumblr_lhvuwqehHA1qem6ty

IMG 3: No progress after clicking on download

http://qcfailed.tumblr.com/photo/1280/3780861509/3/tumblr_lhvuwqehHA1qem6ty

P.S: I need to provide link to my system ppl use windows to schedule the downloads. Our mac machines download limits are throttled.

Update - **Solution**:

It is a stupid error msg from Apple. I was able to proceed to download once I agreed the updated license terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a stupid error msg from Apple. I was able to proceed to download once I agreed the updated license terms.

Thanks all for sharing valuable insights.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue, however setting my browsers user agent to `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.127 Safari/534.16` did the trick for me.

I'd try again if I were you, the "Access Denied" error may just have been a coincidence?

Comment: Thank you davgothic. I guess you should have agreed licence terms before proceeding the download after changing user-agent string.

Comment: I give you a UP vote for sharing the UserAgent string for users.

Answer (score 0):

There has been talk of Apple using the device IDs built into Intel Macs to regulate software. That is how they make the app store work, I believe. It's possible the web page checks for that ID and cannot find it on a PC.

Comment: Thnx TechZen, we were able to download the previous versions including xcode 3.2.5 and xcode4 beta without any issues. Also I'm surprised to know browser can send device ID.

Comment: I was just speculating based on some other speculation I've read. Apple is very interested in content licensing and I think moving Xcode to a $5 download is part of that.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that I can download Xcode 4.1 for Snow Leopard if I change the user agent in Mozilla Firefox to "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.50" (without quotes). But without the change of user agent I could not.